# Is Resharper correct?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

I just installed Reshaper 4.5 and it has come up with the following suggestions:

```
return this.GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0; -- REMOVE this.

new string[] { this.ID.ToString(), this.Registration } -- REMOVE string, MAKE ANONYMOUS TYPE

int i = Method.GetNumber(); -- REPLACE int WITH var
```

Should I do these?

I think in some cases it is going to make the code less readable but will it improve performance? what are the benefits of making these changes?

Thanks

Comment: There's only one Rigobert Song. Be sure to check out the various dup occurrences of the subquestions of this on this forum.

Comment: Try installing StyleCop and StyleCop-for-ReSharper which will give you Microsoft's recommended coding style guidelines. You'll need to tweak R#'s rules to match though. As for the use of var, we always use it internally as it helps readability in our opinion - types are for the compiler, not humans.

Comment: Hm. I always have used the type -- I guess I feel like you should be aware of what you are getting back from your lambda expressions, and it helps a bit if you are specifying it outright.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but using `Any()` instead of `Count() == 0` is a better option as the latter might have to enumerate the entire collection to tell you whether it is empty or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) The explicit `this` pointer is only necessary when the reference would otherwise be ambiguous. Since `GetRuleViolations` is defined on the type, you most likely do not need `this`.

Another point here is that if `GetRuleViolations` return an `IEnumerable` of something, you will generally be much better off using `Any()` instead of `Count() == 0` as you risk enumerating the entire sequence.

2) String can be inferred from the initialization.

3) Resharper prefers `var` over specific types.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the obvious benefit of your little square going green, if you are writing code that will be maintained by someone else later, it makes good sense not to use your personal preference in coding syntax. Resharper is becoming useful in formatting code in a way that is recognisable to a very wide audience.

I belong to the school of thought that says it doesn't matter who's way is right. If we all stick to a pattern, we'll all find it easier to read each others code.

So, in my humble opinion, don't change the default resharper settings. Just accept that if you use the defaults, you make life simple for everyone.

Comment: I agree with you on using the tools defaults. Unfortunately from what I've seen, I don't like Resharper's defaults

Comment: I would always change the 'var' setting of resharper to explicit type because of SECURITY. Readable is fine, but it can do severe damage after someone refactors.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is for the purpose, if you want to make "GetRuleViolations()" a static method. Then you have not to remove the "this" identifier.

Answer (score 1):

For the 3rd one - the one that annoys me the most. It provides the reader with less information and i think it's just a matter of showing off a newish feature.

I'd say - use var when you know the return type and use the correct object type when you do not like this:

```
var reader = new XmlReader(....  // Implicit
XmlReader reader = SomeClass.GetReader() // Explicit when you can't be sure
```

Answer (score 0):

First one: Resharper is asking about removing `this` which is just a style thing to me. Nothing more, keeping it won't harm performance in any way. It is just a matter of readability.

For second and third: Resharper normally prefers using `var` instead of specific data type, that's why the suggestions. I believe it is a matter of personal choice and provides no extra gain other than readability.

Answer (score 0):

The first seems unclear to me. You usually don't have to prefix `this.` as long as there are no ambiguities, which I cannot tell from this example. Resharper is probably right. The other two won't improve performance, the compiled result will be the same. It's just a matter of taste and, of course, your coding guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The first one should be configurable. As far as I remember, you can tell ReSharper whether you want to have "this." in front of only fields, methods, both or none.

Using "var" will not change anything in the generated CIL code, so the performance will stay the same. I haven't used ReSharper for some time and I don't know why it promotes anonymous types so aggressively, but one advantage of "var" is that it's more resistant to change.

Meaning if, instead of calling Method.GetNumber(), you called a wrapper, eg. Filter(Method.GetNumber()) in the same line that returns a Nullable, you won't have to update the variable's type.

Answer (score 0):

None of these will have any effect on performance, *only* on readability.

I find suggestions 1 and 2 to be more readable, and 3 less readable than your original code.

But you don't need to just follow these suggestions if, e.g., you find them less readable or if they violate your company's code style standard. When you put the cursor on the squiggly line, press Alt-Enter to show the list of Contex Actions. One of them will be to to change the severity of the inspection; you can not show it at all or show it as a hint. You can find a complete list of inspections at **ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Inspection Severity**.