# How to pass DataTable.Select() result to a new DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a `DataTable` named `dt2` with data. I am calling its `Select` method to get some specific rows.

```
DataRow[] foundRows;

expression = "parent_id=1";

foundRows = dt2.Select(expression);
```

How can I pass the `Select`-method result to a new `DataTable` – say `FilteredData`?

Answer (score 69):

You can use [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx), available on `IEnumerable<DataRow>` types.

```
var filteredData = dt2.Select(expression).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 19):

Just for clarity, the `Select` method returns an array of type `DataRow`.  That's why we need to use `CopyToDataTable()`. Alex's answer is good.  However, if the `Select` didn't return any rows, `CopyToDataTable()` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

So test that there is at least one `DataRow` before using the `CopyToDataTable()`.

```
var filteredDataRows = dt2.Select(expression);

var filteredDataTable = new DataTable();

if(filteredDataRows.Length != 0)
    filteredDataTable = filteredDataRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: why use `var filteredDataRows` instead of `DataTable[] filteredDataRows`.  your solution works great so I am just curious

Comment: @DaveHampel Use `var` when you are a bit lazy or for better oversight in the code, the variable names are aligned over each other. It means the same and compiles to the same and are indeed strongly typed. It's just not explicit. I normally use `var` when it's obvious from the assignment. I don't do `DataTable table = New DataTable();` but I do use `MyFancyClass mfc = SomeFunctionReturningAnMFC()`  More info at https://intellitect.com/when-to-use-and-not-use-var-in-c/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868500/1093940

Answer (score 16):

Why not use a `DataView` instead?

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt2);
view.RowFilter = "parent_id = 1";
```

`DataView` will behave in very much the same way that a `DataTable` would with the added benefit that any change(s) to the underlying `DataTable` (`dt2` in this case) would be automatically reflected in the `DataView`.