# Unable to copy datatable with datatable.select

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I want to create a copy of a datatable. I am not sure what is the correct way to do it. So, I decided to use

```
DataTable filteredData = sourceDataTable.Select(expression).CopyToDataTable();
```

as mentioned in this post - [How to pass DataTable.Select() result to a new DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883537/how-to-pass-datatable-select-result-to-a-new-datatable)

I tried to use it by setting expression = "where 'TRUE' = 'TRUE'". I hoped that this will not filter any rows from original data table, ie full copy. But, I got the error - System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Missing operand after ''TRUE'' operator.

How do I copy a datatable easily ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from Winney response you could use DataTable.Copy (and probably is the best option in your case), but if you still want to  use `Select` then don't pass any filter expression

```
 DataTable filteredData = sourceDataTable.Select().CopyToDataTable();
```

[DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h71xaeh0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload that doesn't accept any parameter and thus select everything is present in the DataTable

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> Copy creates a new DataTable with the same structure and data as the original DataTable.

```
var copiedDataTable = sourceDataTable.Copy();
```